# Custom Mode Player2 error

Tags: screeps

On screeps custom mode player1 works fine, but when i switch to player 2, i get this error:

```
cannot read property 'main' of undefined
```

I also get this error when I add screeps.

```
cannot read property role of undefined
```

I use the role property to categorize my creeps and tell them what to do. I am unable to add a role to these new screeps. I think the reason for this is that they don't have any memory for me to add to. Why is this happening? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the bug, and I'm unsure if the editor is showing me player 2.

(which for me should be empty for me, after digging into the local storage and pasting that into a json editor like https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

So the screeps simulator can't find code for player 2 (which should be an object containing at least the property 'main'), but that is undefined.

I wonder if those running the screeps site knows more...

tldr; Yeah, I can totally reproduce the same bugs